# Java process.waitFor() returns with inconsistent value

Tags: java, subprocess, exit-code

Use `process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("other.sh")` to lauch other.sh who exits with 1, however, `process.waitFor()` returns with 0. Under Linux RedHat 7.

other.sh just starts another Java process that returns by `System.exit(1)`.

I've seen the same problem in https://coderanch.com/t/326568/java/exitValue-returns-inconsistent-values. However, it said that this was a JDK bug in 1.4 and was fixed already. However, I am using JDK 1.8.

I just want to know if there are any other possibilities leading to such weird behavior? Now our customer and we are both frustrated with this incredible issue.

Comment: Does `other.sh` exit with the exit code of the Java program it starts?

Comment: Yeah, shell will shadow the exit code. Begin your shell script with `set -e` for error propagation.

Comment: @Horn, yes, it does. The java program is the last command executed in other.sh

Comment: @Hegedus, this does not make sense. We never have such issue reported from our other customers, which means this is not a common case. In other environments, the program works fine without `set -e`.

Comment: Launch `other.sh` from the command line and check its exit code by means of `echo $?`.

Comment: @Kock, did, `echo $?` shows 1 as expected.