# Process.waitFor() returns 0 eventhough batch file being called exits with an errorcode other than 0

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm starting a process (.bat) in java using java.lang.Process

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait test.bat");
exitCode = process.waitFor();
```

The .bat process inturn calls .exe file, this .exe returns an exit code !=0 on error cases.

```
START /W test.exe
EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I want to get back the exit code returned from the batch file, but still I get back exitcode=0 always. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982666/java-process-waitfor-returns-with-inconsistent-value) but does not help.

Please let me know how can I get back the actual returned exit code from the process.

Comment: Are you sure test.exe is returning the correct exit code?

Comment: yes, in batch file I have checked ```IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO error code=%ERRORLEVEL% ``` and the exit code is correctly shown. For example error code= 13

Comment: I don't see `/W` btw. But I do see `/WAIT`, which is probably what you want

Comment: I do use /wait. Sorry, I missed to mention it before. I have now included it in my question.

Comment: Well `/WAIT` is still not showing in the batch file itself, And you don't need start elsewhere (or wait for that matter)

Comment: Alright, I tried ```START /WAIT test.exe``` but still the same behavior

Comment: Ok. Can you tighten up the editing to show the accurate code?

Comment: Why not run the .exe directly from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking Java to launch `CMD.EXE` with the command `start /wait test.bat` which starts a second `CMD.EXE` process. There is `EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%` in the second `CMD.EXE` but there is no call in the scriptlet which tells the first `CMD.EXE` to use the status code as `EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%`. Thus you don't get the non-zero code of `test.bat` passed up to first `CMD.EXE`.

The fix is easy as you don't need to use `start /wait`, just change the command to avoid second `CMD.EXE` process and then the `EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%` of the batch script applies to the only `CMD.EXE`:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c test.bat");
```

Note that `Runtime` is not a good way to launch sub-processes, use `ProcessBuilder` instead with cmd passed as `String[]` not `String` so that you don't need to escape spaces in parameters.

Heed the warnings of the `Process` javadoc: **failure
to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of
the process may cause the process to block, or even deadlock**. This means you should consume STDERR + STDOUT on different threads, or redirect STDERR to STDOUT, or redirect them to files or inherit IO streams - otherwise you may encounter problems. Many examples shown in StackOverflow won't work correctly.